# Can anyone get app-engine plugin working with Grails on mac os x?

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, groovy

I have been trying for 4 days to get app-engine and grails working together on my mac to no avail. I am using  latest groovy/grails and appengine sdk versions. Im following the app-engine plugin step by step on the grails site..
http://grails.org/plugin/app-engine

Groovy Version: 1.7.1 JVM: 1.5.0_22
Grails 1.3.0.RC1
echo $APPENGINE_HOME reveals 
 
/Users/markstim/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2

I perform the following steps
 1. `grails create-app myapp`
 2. `cd myapp; grails list-plugins`    reveals 
 `hibernate           1.3.0.RC1        --  Hibernate for Grails`
 `tomcat              1.3.0.RC1        --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails`
 add the following line to Config.groovy 
 `google.appengine.application="myapp"`
 install the plugin for app-engine `grails install-plugin app-engine` and answer 'jpa' when asked (no errors yet)

installed plugins list now looks like
app-engine          0.8.9            --  Grails AppEngine plugin
gorm-jpa            0.7.1            --  GORM-JPA Plugin
 then `grails run-app` and get this error as the server is coming up...

```
[java] WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext 

resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: 

Could not create a new instance of class [GormJpaGrailsPlugin]!:
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.grails.jpa.JpaPluginSupport
```

then if i navigate to localhost:8080 I get

HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /myapp. Reason:

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Powered by Jetty://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost:8080 is your application.  You do not need to add 'myapp' to your path.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Will it play in app engine](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine?pli=1) you have to use `grails app-engine run`

Comment: umm scratch that.. running app-engine run used to blow up but now it does work in that the server comes up clean but I can't navigate to the app, it says "not found" if i hit localhost:8080/myapp, probably a config file, I'll investigate and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with tgd25 - you will need to remove /myapp that is why you are getting a 404.

Oddly enough, after having reached the same exception as you did with Grails 1.3RC1 on a Mac, I managed to get 'grails app-engine run' to startup with the DataNucleus enhancer and one (1) domain class just to test.

However, on a save, the webapp spews the following exception.  See accompanying [JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1375):

> ```
>  [java] 2010-04-17 21:48:05,675 [13387359@qtp-10769461-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - This operation requires a transaction yet it is not active
>  [java] javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: This operation requires a transaction yet it is not active
>  [java]     at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.assertIsActive(EntityManagerImpl.java:846)
>  [java]     at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:545)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate$8.doInJpa(JpaTemplate.java:290)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:183)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.flush(JpaTemplate.java:288)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
>  [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
>  [java]     at org.grails.jpa.JpaPluginSupport$__clinit__closure3_closure7_closure14.doCall(JpaPluginSupport.groovy:471)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
>  [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:307)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:63)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
>  [java]     at pollster.BookController$_closure4.doCall(script12715407593811946448835.groovy:24)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
>  [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
>  [java]     at pollster.BookController$_closure4.doCall(script12715407593811946448835.groovy)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>  [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
>  [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
>  [java]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>  [java]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
>  [java]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:915)
>  [java]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
>  [java]     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
>  [java]     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:378)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:245)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:200)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:137)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:88)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:256)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
>  [java]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
>  [java]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>  [java]     at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:283)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:259)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:252)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:187)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:245)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:136)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:101)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:67)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:63)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>  [java]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>  [java]     at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>  [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>  [java]     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the tomcat plugin before mine worked. I think that's where the confusion comes in - tomcat serves the app at localhost:8080/appname whereas app engine plugin serves it off the root.

On my Mac with latest grails/appengine I couldn't get the current app-engine plugin [0.8.9] to work; I used the 0.8.8 version.

To run it, I just used "grails run-app".

Hope this helps.

Comment: good tip, I'll try the 0.8.8 version and let you know... I suspected some unhappy marriage of versions.